# Powershell - convert multiple coulmns CSV to two column CSV or UNPIVOT

Tags: powershell, csv, transform, transpose

[I have a CSV, which i wanted to convert to two column(Timestamp , value) CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYkrO.png)

i want an output csv like below

9/6/2019 1:00:00 -    305

9/6/2019 2:00:00 -   284

9/6/2019 3:00:00 -   268

-

-

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please show your code. We expect that you try to solve your problem yourself first.

Comment: In addition, please _edit the question_ and explain what's the extraction rule. It looks like you have combined date and hour for the 1st column. What about other columns?

Answer (score 1):

For the shake of a general reusable `UnPivot-Object` function:

**Data example**

```
$Table = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Hour,9/6/2019,9/7/2019,9/8/2019
1,305,293,257
2,284,273,241
3,268,256,227
'@
```

**UnPivot function**

```
Function UnPivot-Object {
    [CmdletBinding()][OutputType([Object[]])]Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLine = $True)]$InputObject
    )
    Process {
        $Properties = $InputObject.PSObject.Properties
        $Row = ($Properties | Select-Object -First 1).Value
        $Properties | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{Row = $Row; Column = $_.Name; Value = $_.Value}
        }
    }
}; Set-Alias UnPivot UnPivot-Object
```

**Result**

```
$Table | UnPivot

Row Column   Value
--- ------   -----
1   9/6/2019 305
1   9/7/2019 293
1   9/8/2019 257
2   9/6/2019 284
2   9/7/2019 273
2   9/8/2019 241
3   9/6/2019 268
3   9/7/2019 256
3   9/8/2019 227
```

**Specific to your question**

```
$Table | UnPivot | Sort Column | ForEach {'{0} {1:##}:00:00 - {2}' -f $_.Column, $_.Row, $_.Value}

9/6/2019 1:00:00 - 305
9/6/2019 2:00:00 - 284
9/6/2019 3:00:00 - 268
9/7/2019 1:00:00 - 293
9/7/2019 2:00:00 - 273
9/7/2019 3:00:00 - 256
9/8/2019 1:00:00 - 257
9/8/2019 2:00:00 - 241
9/8/2019 3:00:00 - 227
```